# how to add css to each step of jquery slider?

Tags: jquery, slider

I want to add different background color to different steps of jquery slider. Is there any way i can do it?
I am trying to build a slider similar to this..[subaru](http://www.subaru-elaion.com/#/Seguimiento/20-probando-la-forester)
Here it is done using flash. I am trying to do the same in jquery. Any help would be appreciated. I am not an expert in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by setting a background image of your colours to the `ui-slider-horizontal` class.

```
.ui-slider-horizontal
{
    background-image: url('slider_bg.png') 50% 50% repeat-x;
}
```

the image would be a horizontal iamge that would be the same width and height of your slider, and also would be designed to have the same amount of segments for each slide.

An example of how a background image has been used you can check the jQuery site here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#multiple-vertical

Comment: The slider width would vary dynamically depending on the width of the browser window. Is there any way to apply css to each step specifically?

Comment: this would not be a problem as you slider would be a specific width, regardless of the browsers view, if its a case of 100% then you just set the image to 100% aswell.

Comment: But here, we are giving a background image to the whole slider. I want a method to access each step individually 'coz the color of each step need to be changed depending on the user input. If You go through the web page which i had given as reference, there is an option at the bottom right to enable video/pictures/text and the same would be reflected in the slider. This can be done by switching background image of the slider, but is there a better way. Thanks for your help, RobertPitt :)